# How to change screen size of TN5250 (scottklement software) emulator?

Tags: terminal, ibm-server

In it's documentation, it is mentionned the user can select a terminal size (24x80 or 27x132).
http://www.scottklement.com/tn5250/windocs.html#AEN155

But at any other moment this information is explained either how to do it...

I speak of this software:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/tn5250/

The settings apply through a profile file...

Which settings do you use to switch to 27x132? Is it even possible?

My profile:

```
profile1 {
  host = x.x.x.x
  map=297
  env.DEVNAME=XXXTN5250
  # 27x132
  env.TERM=IBM-3477-FC
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works automaticaly. But you need to NOT set anything in 80 columns. Because it would stuck the terminal in this resolution.

So, this works

```
env.TERM=IBM-3477-FC
```

But nothing works also well.